# Ternary operator casts integer

Tags: java, implicit-conversion, type-conversion

Please have a look into the below code

```
int a =10;
int b =20;
System.out.println((a>b)?'a':65);//A
System.out.println((a>b)?a:65);//65
System.out.println((a>b)?"a":65);//65
```

Can somebody explain me why it is displaying "A" if I made variable `'a'` as a character? And it should display 65 if I made `"a"` as a string?

Comment: Because 65 is the decimal value of the character `A`.

Comment: See type tables here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25

Comment: For the second question (the last line), I think that the number 65 gets converted to a string, which then displays as "65".  Basically the type of the ternary is always the type of the first argument that could be returned.

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is documented in the [JLS - 15.25. Conditional Operator ? :](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) :

> If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte, short, or char, and the other operand is a constant expression ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) of type int whose value is representable in type T, then the type of the conditional expression is T

When you write

```
(a > b) ? 'a' : 65
```

the second type is converted to a `char`.

Go through the JLS, it explains the behavior (same approach) in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

When your line `System.out.println((a>b)?'a':65);//A` is executed, JVM sees that your condition is false, so it will output 65. Now, you have provided 'a' as first possible output, 65 will be converted to char and 'A' will be returned, which has ASCII value 65.

Answer (score 0):

Ternary Operator work as if-then-else statement. Your getting those result because of autoboxing/unboxing rules for the conditional operator mentioned in JLS section 15.25

first line **System.out.println((a>b)?'a':65);**
condition is false so else block will print 
value of else block is treated as **char** because if block contain a **char** variable.

Second line **System.out.println((a>b)?a:65);**
condition is false so else block will print 
value of else block is treated as **int** because if block contain a **int** variable. here 65 is int value.

Third line **System.out.println((a>b)?"a":65);**
condition is false so else block will print 
value of else block is treated as **String** because if block contain a **String** variable. here 65 is a String not int.

I have checked the JLS. for more info refer official [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25-300-A) here